# R skewed colours when drawing TIFF image

Tags: r

I'm trying to plot a GeoTIFF I made in ArcGIS as the background canvas to some maps, but I've hit a wall getting the colours right.

The ArcGIS output:

[image: ArcGIS output]

But the same GeoTIFF - read into R with `readGDAL() {rgdal}` and drawn with `image()` - produces this:

[image: Drawn in R with image()]

I've tried playing around with colour options - e.g. the colour schemes (`rainbow`, `heat.colors`, `topo.colors`, `terrain.colors`) are severely limited, and `grey()` produces a uniform grey box of customisable tone!

Most grateful for any advice on how to plot the GeoTIFF's true colours, or alternatively something not too garish.

(The functions I used are literally the forms I've given - no additional arguments or settings)

thanks in advance

Robin

Comment: help(SGDF2PCT)         .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try reading it with the raster package into a 'stack' (it should have three bands), then using plotRGB from the raster package.

```
require(raster)
map = stack("mymap.tif")
plotRGB(map)
```